# Pass a string to javascript function from render_field tag in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-widget-tweaks

I can pass a string value to `javascript` function `onblur` when using plain `html` tag as shown below:

```
<input type="password"  name="l_password" onblur="passwordValidation(this,'id_lpassword_error')" />
```

but when i try to do the same thing for `render_field` tags it doesnt work. i get error `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder`

```
{%render_field form.password onblur="passwordValidation(this,'id_lpassword_error')" %}
```

how can i pass the string `'id_lpassword_error'` to a `javascript` function from the render_field tag in Django?

Comment: What is actually rendered when you use `render_field`?  Just saying it 'doesn't work' isn't super clear ;)

Comment: error : TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render_field` is doing its own custom parsing of that tag, and it looks like it [treats double quotes and single quotes the same](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks/blob/master/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py#L122).  So it is probably looking for the tag to finish after your first single quote.

It looks like using the filter [attr](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks#attr) should work, since it is [using Django's built-in template tag parsing system](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks/blob/master/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py#L41), which almost definitely can deal with different types of quotes properly.

So, if I'm understanding this right, something like:

`{{form.password|attr:"onblur:passwordValidation(this,'id_lpassword_error')" }}`

Let us know if that works.